# ¿Es posible poner una imagen con `bootstrap` y que esta no cambie de tamaño?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Es posible poner una imagen y que esta no cambie de tamaño al cambiar la resolución del navegador, estoy usando `bootstrap` para maquetar, pero las imágenes automáticamente las adapta a la resolución?

Comment: ¿Cómo estás poniendo las imágenes en Bootstrap? Deberías añadir el código que tienes para que podamos reproducir el problema y encontrar una solución. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 4):

Saludos una de las opciones es que cuando insertas una imagen les declares el ancho y alto de manera fija de lo siguientes modos

```
<img src="mi_foto.jpg" width="500" height="600">
```

O por medio de una hoja de estilos a través de su id

```
<img src="mi_foto.jpg" id="foto_mia">
```

Y luego en tu hoja de estilos personal lo declaras así:

```
#foto_mia{
 width: 900px;
 height: 500px;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que para lograr lo anterior en tu HTML primero debes declarar el link de llamado a bootstrap  y luego a tu css personal, así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Aunque te aclaro que las imágenes con bootstrap solo se hacen responsivas agregando la siguiente clase en la etiqueta img y solo en ese caso:

```
 <img class="img-responsive" src="self.jpg" alt="self">
```

Saludos